# WPF. How do I create many LIstViews with the same look

Tags: wpf, listview, styles

I've defined a listview in my recent project and realized that I will be using more listviews looking exactly the same and having the same solumns. Since I'm new to WPF am I curious of teh best way to do this. Is it to create a usercontrol? Use styles? I've tried to use styles but it didnt work the way I was hoping. I tried to set the "View" property using style, like this.

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="View">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
```

But it didnt work so I'm asking for your opinion?! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `Setter.Value` tag, and you don't need the `ListView.View` tag :

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="View">
        <Setter.Value>
            <GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should go ahead and put the common properties into a Style and link to it from all the similar controls...

The issue I see from your brief code-snippet is that you don't need the ListView.List element (the A.B XAML Syntax means that you're setting the B property on A.)

```
<Style ...
  <Setter Property="PropertyName">
     <ValueObj/>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="View">
     <GridView ... />
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that hasn't been discussed:  you can define the `ListView` in a `DataTemplate`, and use that `DataTemplate` to display the various collections you'll be showing.  For instance, if your items collections are all of type `MyCollectionType`, you can do this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="myNamespace:MyCollectionType">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <!-- define everything here -->
    </ListView>
</DataTemplate>

...

<StackPanel>
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding OneCollection}"/>    
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding AnotherCollection"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and the `OneCollection` and `AnotherCollection` properties in your view model will both be rendered as `ListView` controls with the same layout.