# How do I specify common layout markup or rules for controls in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm a WCF newbie, and I wonder, is it possible to declare in XAML that *all* my TextBoxes should have a height of 26, for example? That is, not to set the height of each item individually?

Comment: There is a link to [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886992/wpf-how-do-i-create-many-listviews-with-the-same-look) on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a style for your textbox

This will style the textbox when required

```
<Style x:Key="myTextBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="26" />
</Style>

<TextBox Text="Hi" Style="{StaticResource myTextBoxStyle}"/>
```

This will style all the textboxes

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="26" />
</Style>
```

Put your Style into your resources block